# C++ Unmanaged dll - Instantiation and Dispose Issue - C#

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I have a C++ unmanaged DLL that I'm using on C# 2.0 over a web application (IIS6). To use this DLL I have created a wrapper using the utility `tlbimp` from .Net. 
I want that DLL to be created (instantiated) EACH time a new user session occurs. And be released (disposed) when the user log off the application and closes the browser.

The issue I'm experiencing is that now when the first user connects to the application, the object is being created, but when another users log in, the same previous object is being reused, and when each user disconnects from the system, the object is not being released until I restart IIS.

I know about this behaviour because that component (DLL) insert a new registry at the EventLog each time it's being instantiated and each time it's being disposed. And in the case I mentioned, there's only one creation registry and non dispose registry until I restart IIS, then there's the dispose registry.

Here is the code I implemented to try to dispose the object, but it doesn't seems to have any effect.

```
public class ComObject: IDisposable
    {
        private ComClientClass_objCom;
        private bool _isDisposed = false;

        public ComObject()
        {
            _objCom = new ComClientClass();
        }

        ~ComObject()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //finalize unmanaged resources
                _objCom = null;
            }
            _isDisposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

I don't know if this behaviour has something to do with IIS configuration or something.

Can anybody explain me please why this is happening? Because as far as I know this same DLL was being used with the old ASP and back then it worked OK, so I assume it's some kind of issue with the GC in .Net.

Comment: _objCom = null doesn't do anything in terms of releasing the unmanaged resource; what is the unmanaged resource you need to release?

Comment: if you have access to the original asp code you need to have a look at it - there are a number of issues with the above, including the fact that you are not releasing the com object and that even if you do release it according to the behavior you have specified simoultaneous requests would be using the same object even if you did release, and even worse when one request released the other request would then attempt to use the released object

Comment: As far as I'm informed there's no good way of unloading a DLL from IIS without restarting it because IIS caches and reuses DLLs. I think you can only dispose it by restarting the MTS using the commands 'net stop iisadmin /y', 'mtxstop' and 'net start w3svc'. This most likely won't really help you though. :/

Comment: And what about doing this: Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_objCom) ? does it has some effect on releasing the object?

Comment: @dice about your comment, maybe I have a misleading concept about the way .Net operates under IIS, because I thought that each session a user starts, recreates all the variables for that specific session, so you mean that the same COM reference will be used across all the sessions?

Comment: @lidermin - Yes...If you think .NET operates under IIS then you have been mislead.

Comment: @lidermin - that deservers a whole new question in its own right, but suffice it to say any native dll will only be loaded once by IIS, so the behavior depends on the implementation of the dll.  I would expect to be calling some sort of factory to get the actual object to work with - but this is implementation dependant.